# how to access saved data in $localStorage in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, rootscope

i am working on MEAN app, after successful user login i want to save returned user data in localStorage in browser so that i can use it further, i am using ngStorage module. where i am able to save user data in browser's localstorage. here is my code in LoginController :

```
 function loginController($http, $location, $rootScope,$localStorage){
    var vm = this;
    vm.signIn = signIn;

 function signIn() {      
    $http({
        url: '/login',
        method: 'post',
        data: vm.login
    }).then(function(respond) { 
     if(respond.data){ 
        $localStorage.userData = respond.data;   
         var info = $localStorage.userData;         
        $rootScope.userInfo = info; 
         $location.path('/dashboard/'+respond.data._id);
      }else{
         $location.path('/');
        }
```

no when i access $rootScope in my another controller i can get value that is stored in $localStorage. even in my chrome browser i can see from inspect that data is stored in $localStorage. **BUT when i refresh my page** i can see there is still data in browser in localStorage but not in my $rootscope. my rootScope gets null data after page refreshing, i would really appreciate any suggestion on how to access those data and stored in rootScope.

Comment: you can trigger some init function at the time of template initialization using ng-init and restore the data from storage. or you can write state resolve function to do the same..

Comment: $rootScope behaves like javascript variable i.e. it gets destroyed when you reload the location.why are you using $rootScope when the data can be easily accessed through $localStorage in any point of your application.

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked can we access it  setting on one controller and getting data in another controller

Comment: why do you save the localStorage in the rootScope?IMHO it isn't necessary. You can access to localStorage every where in your code directly

Comment: @kisor yes, your $localstorage.userData is available on every nooks and corners of your application if you inject $localstorage service that comes with the ngStorage :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, i have said, `$rootScope` gets destroyed when you reload the location like any javascript variable. Your localStorage data is accessible everywhere throughout your application until you destory, remove, or reset it.

```
    function loginController($http, $location, $rootScope, $localStorage) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.signIn = signIn;

                function signIn() {
                    $http({
                            url: '/login',
                            method: 'post',
                            data: vm.login
                        }).then(function(respond) {
                                if (respond.data) {
                                    $localStorage.userData = respond.data;
                                    var info = $localStorage.userData;
                                    $rootScope.userInfo = info;
                                    $location.path('/dashboard/' + respond.data._id);
                                } else {
                                    $location.path('/');
                                }

      function anyController($scope, $localStorage) {
                                       console.log($localStorage.userData);
                                    }
```

An example where you redirect to the main state if there is no userData where you are accessing the data via `$localStorage` in the module run function.

```
angular.module("yourAppName")
  .run(function ($rootScope, $state,$localStorage) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      if(toState.name == 'app') return;
      if (!$localStorage.userData){
        $state.transitionTo("app");
        event.preventDefault(); 
        return;
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

retrieve user data from local-storage when app reloads

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
  if(localStorage['userData'])
  {
    $rootScope.userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
  }
});
```